# can't edit PHP files on server; getting HTML output instead

Tags: php, joomla, lamp, webdav

I've a strange problem. Every php file on my server appears corrupted when I try to edit it with dreamweaver or any text editor. When I open a php file on the server to view the source code, it shows the output html code instead of the actual php code. For example, I uploaded a php file with just one line of code (`<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`) to output the php info of the server. The page shows alright as expected in a browser; however, when I try to view or edit the source code on the server with notepad++, dreamweaver or any text editor, it shows the output html (about 870 lines of html code) instead of the actual one line of php code that I put inside in the php file.

Php files with connection strings to a database or include files open as blank in text editors. In dreamweaver, I get an error that ‘file cannot be found’ for these type of php files – apparently referring to its inability to resolve the database connection or the include file. Other script files (like configuration.php) also open as blank.

This problem has affected all php files in my joomla site (joomla 2.5), and even files that are not part of joomla. It even affects php files that are outside the htdocs folder. However, all other script files (css, js, xml) open correctly in text editors.

Even strange, this has not affected the performance of joomla or the other non-joomla pages on the website. The website works perfectly, except that I can't view or edit php source code on the server. I had the same joomla installation running perfectly on localhost and on another remote server before I copied all the files to this new LAMP Server.

I connect to the server via Webdav on Windows 7. It's shared hosting on a university server. I've contacted the IT department and they have assured me over and over again that they have checked everything and the problem is not from their end.

Any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: however you are retrieving the files, they are being passed through the web server first.

Answer (score 3):

The files aren't corrupted at all. What you are doing is viewing their output after the webserver has *served* them to you.

When you have files on a server, you can't just tell notepad or dreamweaver to open *http://www.example.com/index.php* as this will mean that the webserver will pass it to your program as if it was requested by a browser - meaning that all the PHP code is executed and file contents are the HTML output.

To view the actual code in them, you will need to either have direct access to the server (if it is at your office, home or whatever) where you can just browse to the right folder (/var/www/index.php for example or C:\server\www\index.php) or much more commonly, you will need to download the files via FTP or some other similar manner. When you do this, the server will give you the files directly without first *running* them as if a web browser had asked for them.

Comment: Thanks guys, but the problem goes beyond the browser just parsing php code to html before showing the source code. When I copy the file from the server to desktop, it's still not able to open. I've tried that using both webdav and windows network drive mapping.I don't have ftp access.

When I copy a file with windows mapped drive, i'm able to view the source code on the server for the few mins, after which the problem resumes. However, when I copy with webdrive, i'm not able to view source code at all.

Answer (score 2):

WebDAV is not well suited for editing web content, as it fails to distinguish between user access to files (e.g, someone looking at your Joomla site) and administrative access to files (e.g, you trying to edit the Joomla configuration file) -- and this is what is causing your problems. Nothing is being "corrupted", but the web server simply isn't allowing you to view the source code of PHP files.

You will be much better off using some form of out-of-band access to your web content, such as FTP or Windows file sharing. If this isn't available, complain to your hosting provider until it is.

Comment: Thanks. I think webdav is messing up permissions. I don't have access to ftp. I tried windows mapped drive, and the same thing happens. When i copy a file to desktop and open it on desktop, the same thing happens, which is unusual.